# VS 2010, change location of project file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, location, setup-project

I do not with VS 2010 frequently so my question is "beginner".

VS2010 creates a solution with the folowing directory structure (simplified):

```
/Solution
    solution.sdf
    solution.sln
    solution.suo
    /Solution
       solution.cpp
       solution.vcxproj
       /Debug
       /Release
```

I want to change the directory structure for alredy created project:

```
/Solution
    /Solution
       solution.cpp
       /Projects
           /VS
              solution.sdf
              solution.sln
              solution.suo
              solution.vcxproj
              /Debug
              /Release
```

So the solution file and projects file will be moved into subfolder

```
 /Projects/VS
```

The file solution.sln was enough to edit the path to

```
 = "Solution", "..\..\solution.vcxproj"
```

But how  (and where) to change a location of the project file solution.vcxproj so as to be able to locate all files with the source code.

I am using different compilers so I want to create own subfolder for each development tool.

```
/Projects
    /VS
    /Eclipse
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's wrong with the default folder structure?

Comment: Question updated: I am using more compilers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= "Solution", "..\..\solution.vcxproj"
```

No that's wrong, the .sln file is in the same folder as the .vcxproj file.  So it should read `= "Solution", "solution.vcxproj"`.

The only other patch is that the solution.cpp file is in a non-standard location.  Edit the .vcxproj file and locate the `<ItemGroup>` for the solution.cpp file.  Change it to `Include="..\solution.cpp"`.

Comment: I am sorry, but in the default installation of VS2010 a *.sln file is in different folder than *vcxproj...

Comment: Hmm, no, only if you leave the "Create directory for solution" checkbox ticked.  But that's hardly the point, you've moved stuff around.  So update the .sln and .vcxproj files to match the moves.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. If I left this property unchecked, the solution and project files shared the same directory...