# I want to change the location of .sln and .vcxproj

Tags: c++, visual-studio

below one is the current project structure.

```
- project
  - bin
  - obj
  - include
  - src
    * a.cpp
  * project.sln
  * project.vcxproj
```

But I want to create new directory "project". And move .sln and .vcxproj file into "project" directory.

```
- project
  - bin
  - obj
  - include
  - project
    * project.sln
    * project.vcxproj
  - src
    * a.cpp
```

Here problem occurred. Because `<ItemGroup>` components of vcxproj do not update itself, so .sln cannot load all of my files.

In other words, originally a.cpp is written as "src/a.cpp" in .vcxproj file. but after moving .vcxproj, it still remains as "src/a.cpp" not "../src/a.cpp".

I also saw [VS 2010, change location of project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635085/vs-2010-change-location-of-project-file). But I could not find the automatic way to update vcxproj when it is moved.

Is there any way to achieve it ? or I have to change all of components of .vcxproj manually?

Comment: Hi yldbear77. I'm actually working with VS 2019 and I'm pretty sure that you have to do it the manual way, because VS doesn't provide any option for this. Maybe you should open the `.vcxproj` file with a powerful text editor and search and replace all the pathes of the source files etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio just allows to save the solution file `.sln` at another location. Just select the Solution in the Solution Explorer, go to menu item

> File -> Save >MySolution.sln> As...

and save it under another name and/or location.

The project file `.vcxproj` itself cannot be relocated by a Visual Studio option/menu item. Therefore this has to be done manually and all the pathes to source, resource files etc. shall be updated by the help of a powerful text editor, e.g.

- [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/)
- [PSPad](https://www.pspad.com/en)
- [TextPad](https://www.textpad.com/home)

just doing a search and replace.

Checked with Visual Studio version 16, hence VS 2019. Maybe this option will be available in a future version of Visual Studio.